# React - How to access data set value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rendering list of years (2017,2018,2019 ..etc)

I'm trying to console.log year value

```
   <a href="#" onClick={() => console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-year'))} data-year={year}>{year}</a>
```

I have tried getAttribute but keep getting 'undefined'

```
event.target.getAttribute('data-year')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/83227/

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `()` to `(event)`.

Comment: No luck still : - /

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rejee84L/

Comment: Can you post that as an answer, you deserve the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a data attribute and `event.target.dataset.value`:

```
class ControlText extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }

  update(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.setState({value: event.target.dataset.value});
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    var value = this.state.value;
    return <a type="text" data-value={2017} onClick={this.update.bind(this)} > 2017 </a>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ControlText />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rejee84L/

Answer (score 0):

Your code as posted appears to have a typo--your console.log doesn't having a closing parenthesis. In addition, you don't really need to use event.target.value here. Check it out:

```
<a href="#" onClick={ () => console.log(year) }>{year}</a>
```

When React creates the `<a>` element it knows what your year variable is and can use it in the console.log function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but your example hasn't worked for me